# Visual Studio ignores font setting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts, truetype

I'm trying to change my default text editor font in Visual Studio from Consolas to another monospaced font.  In particular, I want to use the TTF version of Inconsolata I downloaded from the Google font directory.

This new font shows up in the font selection drop down, correctly bolded to indicate it's a monospace font, but when I select it, VS reverts to showing Consolas.  (I know it's ignoring my font settings, because even when I set the size to something like 20, it continues to display the default Consolas at 10 or 11.  What's more, is when I re-open the Options dialog, the font is *still* set to Inconsolata at size 20.  VS is just ignoring the setting and reverting to the default font.

The same problem happens with DejaVu Mono font I downloaded (also a TTF).

Both of these fonts show up correctly in Word and other apps.

Any ideas?

Comment: Document the values of "Show settings for" combo and "Display items" list.

Comment: "Text Editor", and "Plain text", respectively.  Maybe I should have mentioned that other font choices are immediately reflected in the text editor, while these fonts are not.

Comment: Are you sure these are not the OpenType versions of these fonts?  That's their 'native' format, not supported by VS2010.

Comment: The filenames are DejaVuSansMono.ttf and Inconso0.ttf.  Clicking on either font in the Fonts folder brings up the font sample window which reports that both are, indeed, TrueType fonts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're typing the fontsize into the box, which is reflected in the preview but not taken into effect when you click OK.

Select the font size with the dropdown and it should work. I'm using Lucida Console, but it exhibits this behavior even with Segoe UI.

This bug is still present in the Beta (2/29/12)

Comment: I see you said the font size '20' is still shown. I wasn't seeing that behavior so it is probably specific to that font. However this should help some people having the problem I was having